# Can ArcMap perform nested queries, similar to the dynamic analysis capabilities in GeoMedia?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geomedia

I've been asked by a seasoned GeoMedia user if **ArcMap can perform nested queries, similar to the dynamic analysis capabilities in GeoMedia**.

I'm reasonably familiar with ArcMap, but I have zero experience with GeoMedia. I'm pretty sure I understand the principle of the question, that you can have dynamic layers which automatically update as the base data updates, e.g. creating buffers for a points layer, and the buffers layer keeps itself up-to-date automatically as the points layer change, or as the buffer size parameter changes, and this itself cascades down into further dynamic layers.

My initial response was that ModelBuilder could be used to the same end, but it doesn't seem as convenient as how nested queries have been described to me. Personally, I do most of my spatial work in QGIS and SQL Server, and it's been a few years since I regularly used Esri software, so I can't answer with much certainty. **Is there any functionality in ArcMap which similarly achieves *convenient* dynamic analysis?**

Answer (score 1):

The Attribute Assistant, a free addin, can be configured to execute certain methods when a feature is edited or created. You need a Standard or Advanced ArcGIS license. http://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/